# How to make awk print multil row match string in file text, with condition?

Tags: awk

How can I print lines muitil patterns which meet a condition?

For instance for an input file

partially containing the following:

```
ID : 1

Status : Ok

Name : Lulu

Age : 18

State : US




ID : 2

Status : Ok

Name : Master Yi

Age : 22

State : UK



ID : 3

Status : Ok

Name : Garen

Age : 20

State : CA
------------

Codition : IF Age == 20 | print 
----------

ID : 3

Status : Ok

Name : Garen

Age : 20

State : CA
```

please help

Thanks

Comment: You talk about multi patterns, but only look for one pattern. Please elaborate by editing your question. Also, does it have to be `awk`?

Comment: If this file has the fixed set of lines.. than you can do something like  `grep -C4 'Name : Master Yi' filename`

Comment: Please use code formatting for example input and output: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question to include answers to comments. Most importantly, please use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your example file as code. Does it really have so many blank lines? Are there really spaces around the `:`? Ware there really horizontal lines in the file? We need to know the _exact_ format of the file to be able to help you.

Comment: yep. I wanna use awk filter file text with any condition Agem State, Name ,... and output row user that .

Comment: Is `Codition : IF Age == 20 | print ` part of your input file? What is your desired output?

Comment: Is Codition : IF Age == 20 | print  part of your input file? What is your desired output?
=> This input file text and i wanna output file filter output .

Comment: Please edit your question to include the desired output for the example input you provided. Also, include what you have already tried and where you ran into difficultier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is really as you show and you have 4 empty lines between each record, and 3 empty lines between each line of a record, then you can do this:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n\n\n' '/Age : 20\n/' file 
ID : 3

Status : Ok

Name : Garen

Age : 20

State : CA
```

You haven't clarified this, but I suspect that the extra blank lines aren't actually part of your file but only artefacts of your question's formatting, so you have only one blank line between each line of a record and only two blank lines between each record. If so, your input file is like this:

```
ID : 1
Status : Ok
Name : Lulu
Age : 18
State : US


ID : 2
Status : Ok
Name : Master Yi
Age : 22
State : UK

ID : 3
Status : Ok
Name : Garen
Age : 20
State : CA
```

If your file is indeed like this, then you can do:

```
$ awk -v RS= '/Age : 20\n/' file
ID : 3
Status : Ok
Name : Garen
Age : 20
State : CA
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach of first creating an array to map the tags (names) of the fields to their values lets you do what you currently want and enhance it trivially in future to test for compound conditions, print select fields, print fields in a different order or do anything else you might want to do with your `tag:value` type data:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=" : " }
!NF { next }
{
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/ *:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+ *: */,"",val)
    if ( !(tag in tag2val) ) {
        tags[++numTags] = tag
    }
    tag2val[tag] = val
}
tag == "State" {
    if ( tag2val["Age"] == 20 ) {
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            val = tag2val[tag]
            print tag, val
        }
        print ""
    }
    delete tag2val
    numTags = 0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ID : 3
Status : Ok
Name : Garen
Age : 20
State : CA
```